# Scrapy Link extractor doesn't work

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape this page http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/locate_store.cmd?useCurrentLocation=yes&findUSStore=no&findAllStore=false&radius=0&countryCode=CA#results

I have this rule:

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'storeId='),
        callback="parse_item"
    ),
)
```

There are 16 links on the page but this rule finds only 13. If I save that page locally and try then it finds all 16.

It's driving me crazy, what's wrong with this webpage?

Comment: I don't see any links that contain `storeId`. I get a "PAGE NOT FOUND". Are you sure about the link?

Comment: @paultrmbrth Yes, the link does work. You may want to use web proxy because depending on your location some websites may be unavailable.

Comment: Indeed, I checked through a US proxy. `SgmlLinkExtractor` finds less links than a simple check with XPath on the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alternative link extractor like `RegexLinkExtractor` instead of `SgmlLinkExtractor`

```
paul@machine:~$ scrapy shell "http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/locate_store.cmd?useCurrentLocation=yes&findUSStore=no&findAllStore=false&radius=0&countryCode=CA#results"
...
2014-06-11 15:49:43+0000 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2014-06-11 15:49:43+0000 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/locate_store.cmd?useCurrentLocation=yes&findUSStore=no&findAllStore=false&radius=0&countryCode=CA#results> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x2961210>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/locate_store.cmd?useCurrentLocation=yes&findUSStore=no&findAllStore=false&radius=0&countryCode=CA#results>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/locate_store.cmd?useCurrentLocation=yes&findUSStore=no&findAllStore=false&radius=0&countryCode=CA>
[s]   settings   <CrawlerSettings module=None>
[s]   spider     <Spider 'default' at 0x2fab5d0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

In [1]: from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.regex import RegexLinkExtractor

In [2]: lx = RegexLinkExtractor(allow=r'storeId=')

In [3]: lx.extract_links(response)
Out[3]: 
[Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1626', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=3183', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1632', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1627', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1628', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1642', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1641', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1623', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1634', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1625', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1630', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=2176', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1619', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1622', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1599', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.stevemadden.com/custserv/store_details.jsp?storeId=1636', text=u'VIEW STORE DETAILS', fragment='', nofollow=False)]

In [4]: len(lx.extract_links(response))
Out[4]: 16

In [5]: from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

In [6]: lx = SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'storeId=')

In [7]: len(lx.extract_links(response))
Out[7]: 13

In [8]:
```